# Swiping between Watch Now Playing Screen blanks other screen

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I setup the Now Playing screen on my Watch App as per the instructions from Apple - [Adding a Now Playing View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_elements/adding_a_now_playing_view) in Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027)
and from the main screen I go to the next set of screens like this -

```
@IBAction func startButtonPressed() {
      WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.start)
      WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["WorkoutSession", "NowPlaying"], contexts: [0], orientation: WKPageOrientation(rawValue: 0)!, pageIndex: 0)
 }
```

The problem is that when I swipe a few times between the WorkoutSession screen and the Now Playing Screen my workout screen goes blank. Ive tried it with a simple label on a blank screen and it does the same thing, no matter what is on the screen the Now Playing screen blanks the other one. This is on a physical watch not the simulator. Is it because of the way Im navigating to the workout screen and the Now playing screen using `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers` because this is the only way I can make sure there is no close or go back or wipe back action that would wreak the workout session.

Anyone else had this problem with the Now Playing Screen?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No. I just made a button to display the Now Playing screen. I didn’t want to release the app when there was a chance it would display a blank screen with no way to use the app. Most people don’t know the Trick to hold the side button For 1 second and then hold the Digital Crown button to close apps.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Please let me know if you find any solution